# Swift print center of map when user moves the map

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I want to draw a map with Swift under iOS 11. I would like that, when app starts, the map is centered on the position of the user.

The output of the console, when I start the app is:

```
locations = 0.0 0.0
locations = 49.8375375633452 3.45672192960001
locations = 0.0 0.0
locations = 49.8375375633452 3.45672192960001
```

Another problem occurs when I move the map with my finger, I would like to print the coordinates of the center of the map (and if possible, the region displayed on the screen) but nothing happens.

Here is my complete code of the class.

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate {



    var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    func checkLocationAuthorizationStatus() {
        if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .authorizedWhenInUse {
            mapView.showsUserLocation = true
        } else {
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        }
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        checkLocationAuthorizationStatus()
    }


    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!


    var currentLocation = CLLocation()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //For use when the app is open
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        // If location services is enabled get the users location
        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            locationManager.delegate = self
            locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters // You can change the locaiton accuary here.
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        }

        mapView.delegate = self
        mapView.register(MyClassMarkerView.self,
                         forAnnotationViewWithReuseIdentifier: MKMapViewDefaultAnnotationViewReuseIdentifier)
        centerMapOnLocation(location: self.currentLocation.coordinate)

    }

    let regionRadius: CLLocationDistance = 1000

    func centerMapOnLocation(location: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
        let coordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(location,
                                                                  regionRadius, regionRadius)
        print("locations = \(location.latitude) \(location.longitude)")
        mapView.setRegion(coordinateRegion, animated: true)
    }


    // Print out the location to the console
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        if let location = locations.first {
            self.currentLocation = location            
            print("locations = \(location.coordinate.latitude) \(location.coordinate.longitude)")
            locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        }
    }


    // If we have been deined access give the user the option to change it
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        if(status == CLAuthorizationStatus.denied) {
            showLocationDisabledPopUp()
        }
    }

    // Show the popup to the user if we have been deined access
    func showLocationDisabledPopUp() {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Background Location Access Disabled",
                                                message: "In order to deliver pizza we need your location",
                                                preferredStyle: .alert)

        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
        alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

        let openAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Open Settings", style: .default) { (action) in
            if let url = URL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString) {
                UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
            }
        }
        alertController.addAction(openAction)

        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView,
                 calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {
        let location = view.annotation as! myClass
        let launchOptions = [MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey: MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeWalking]
        location.mapItem().openInMaps(launchOptions: launchOptions)
    }

    func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, regionDidChangeAnimated animated: Bool) {
        print ("Here we are")
        var center = mapView.centerCoordinate
        print ("Center is \(center)")
    }

}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you remember to set `self` as `delegate`?

Comment: Yes I did. I have `mapView.delegate = self` declared in the `viewDidLoad`.

Answer (score 1):

Your ViewController also needs to be the `delegate` of the Map View, so hook up your mapview as the delegate in the storyboard, and declare your ViewController to also implement `MKMapViewDelegate` to receive the events you are expecting.

Also, the delegate function you are using does not exactly match the one from `MKMapViewDelegate`, so it does not know which function to call. You should have gotten a yellow warning in Xcode about this. Change it to:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, regionDidChangeAnimated animated: Bool) {
    print ("Here we are")
    var center = mapView.centerCoordinate
    print ("Center is \(center)")
}
```

Comment: Yes, I did. I have `mapView.delegate = self` declared in the `viewDidLoad`.

I also have an extension of the `viewController` that implements `MKMapViewDelegate` in which I define the methods `regionDidChangeAnimated` and `annotationView`.

Comment: Could you update the code in your original question to show the actual code you are using? There's no `mapView.delegate = self` there, nor are you showing how you've written your View Controller extension.

Comment: I tested a much simplified version of your code here and updated my answer above with another thing you were missing.

Comment: Thank you very much, I did not pay attention to the missing `_`.
It's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your class should be declared as follows

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate {
    ....
}
```

Comment: Moved the function from the extension to the viewcontroller class and did that with no success.
I update my class code.